# Android Scroll View: How to load about 2500 guitar chords (i.e. "Em7") into scroll view

Tags: android

The app requires a scrollable list of chords (i.e. "Em7", "C#", etc.) and I'm not sure the best way to get them into the ScrollView.  I can generate a list easily in code (there are about 2500 items...), so it boils down to whether I need all the overhead of a 'Large Text' widget, or can I just have clickable text in the list?  This ScrollView is on an Activity with some text fields and two other ScrollViews that have lists of chord modifiers.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/new_song_name"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:width="400dp"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

<android.support.v7widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText"
    android:id="@+id/view">

    </android.support.v7widget.GridLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        ***android:text="C"***
        //the line above is representative of the list items.
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It does sound like you want a `ListView`. You can set an `onClickListener` for each item in a list which will perform a specific action (usually based on its position in the list or the  data set backing the ListView) [Take a look at the ListView guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

Comment: I think for this case a `GridView` would be better, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: I would agree with `GridView` too - I'm thinking he would like to display the actual chord fingerings just above the name of the chords

Answer (score 0):

use fragment, this link can help you :

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/

Comment: Thanks, I dismissed fragments out of ignorance.  I see the full value of them now!

Answer (score 0):

Dude, why you don't use ListView and ListAdapter ?
and load ChordList from datebase;
So it will be scrolled.

```
ArrayList<String> chords = new ArrayList<>();
chords = getFromDb;
ListView chordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
chordList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, chords ));`
```

`

Comment: I am going to try the GridView to start.  However, I'm always confused when I have an existing Activity (currently with just an EditText, and TextView for a 'song' title) and how to fold the new code into the existing code in NewSong.java.  I've tried to add Gridview code into the existing OnCreate(Bundle...) code.  This is keeping me from understanding how to use the code properly and in the right context.  Thanks again!